# Vertically Align: Middle

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to vertically align the two links to the middle to either side of the logo, but it does not seem to work. Furthermore I want to make this a responsive navigation with both links appearing below the logo in accordion drop down fashion. I have been looking everywhere for the solution but I cannot find one.

HTML

```
<nav>
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Boat</a>
                <ul class="boat">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <img src="images/logo.png"/>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a>
                <ul class="experience">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
                </ul></li>

        </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
* { 
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: 60%;
}


ul#nav {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

ul#nav li {
    width: 125px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right:5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul#nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   width: 125px;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
   background-color: #f3f3f3;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 5px;
   text-align: center;
}

ul.boat, ul.experience {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1em;
   position: absolute;
   top:100%;

}

ul#nav li:hover > a {
   background-color: yellow;
}

ul#nav ul.boat, ul.experience {
   display:none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.boat {
   display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.experience {
   display: block;
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Your HTML isn't valid: `img` can't be a direct child of `ul`, it should be enclosed in another `li` for example

Comment: @FelipeAls, his code is working even though img is placed in the ul

Comment: @Hawk Relying on browsers correcting your mistakes isn't a very robust way of doing things in web front-end world. I've been powned countless times by this so my second step is to verify that my code is at least valid (my first one is verifying I'm refreshing the same page I'm trying to modify ^^, esp. on mondays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul#nav li
{
vertical-align: top; // takes the links to the top
padding-top: 10px; // modify so that it goes to middle
}
```

This code should work if you are trying to place the links in the middle of the image. Do tell me if it works

made a fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/Ff5xk/

Comment: that worked, but the  experience dropdown menu is showing twice the distance between the links

Comment: I want to combine what I doing here with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yK7Qy/ where once the page reduces in size the links appear under the logo

Comment: are you sure the distance between the links is twice the size because i set the sub links to have no padding and the fiddle that i have posted shows exactly the same distance as it was showing when the links were positioned down..and i do not get what you mean by the links to show under the logo when the page reduces in size. please elaborate more on that

Comment: sorry for the experience drop down menu, i have rectified my mistake, please view this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/Ff5xk/1/